# Is there a way to map my document id with toObject?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm deserializing an entire document, to keep things in handy and prevent me to check for each value and construct the object I use

```
myList.add(documentSnapshot.toObject(House::class.java))
```

Now, lets say House is this

```
data class House(val name:String,val:address:String)
```

Now, if I want to also get the House document Id and put it inside my document I do this

```
data class House(val houseId:String,val name:String,val:address:String)
```

But after doing that , the first line of code transforms into this

```
 val houseId = documentSnapshot.id
 val houseName = docuementSnapshot.getString("name")
 val houseAddress = documentSnapshot.getString("address")
 myList.add(House(houseId,houseName,houseAddress))
```

What I want to do is use `.toObject()` to also map that extra field that is the document id inside of it because if the House object expands in size, I will need to hand write again each property, and now think that house has 100 properties and I just need the id of it inside the object. I will need to write off 99 get fields to just place the document Id inside that house object.

Is there a way to map that id to the object without doing the above and just placing `.toObject` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want to do is use .toObject() to also map that extra field that is the document id

This will be possible only if the document already contains the `id` property that holds the document id as a value. If you only have the `name` and the `address`, then you cannot map the `id`, because it doesn't exist in the document. To be able to map all those three properties you should update each and every document in that collection so it contains the document id. If you have lots of documents in the collection, I recommend you use [batch writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes).

Right after that, you'll be able to use:

```
val house = documentSnapshot.toObject(House::class.java)
```

And now this `house` object will contain the `id` too.

Answer (score 4):

You need just add annotation `@DocumentId`

```
data class House(@DocumentId val houseId:String,val name:String,val:address:String)
```